# What is the difference between “nope” and “no”?

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference, negation, slang

What is the difference caused by using “nope” instead of ”no”?

Is it used because “nope” sounds better and not straight like “no”? In some situations, it feels like *nope* is better to use than *no* even though it adds 2 more characters. What is the reason why many use it?

Comment: Not a language expert but nope sounds very much like No Period. As in No that's my final no.

Comment: @Ian, very good observation. StoneyB made a similar conclusion in a comment to an answer, below. ("terminal/dismissive...no, and that's all I have to say")

Comment: A speculative theory about the origin of "Nope" is suggested by the reason cited for Bertrand's use of "you sam" in Kingsley Amis's *Lucky Jim*: http://fiftybooksproject.blogspot.com/2011/07/lucky-jim-by-kingsley-amis.html, search the page for "sam"

Answer (score 80, accepted):

From [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59658/31820), they have no difference in meaning; but *nope* is more informal, only used in a sense of opposite to *yes* (or *yup*). Also, *nope* is not used often in writing.

You wouldn't say "there were nope errors", for example.

Comment: I would note that "nope" is *very* informal.  It is almost never written - just spoken.

Comment: You've added another point in your answer -- "nope" can't be used as a modifier, only as an independent statement.

Comment: I'm not convinced *nope* is *more emphatic*. In fact, I could easily convince myself there are contexts where it's ***less** emphatic*. The most defining characteristic of *nope* is that it tends to be used to convey a *relaxed* attitude. In an "informal" setting such as an argument in a pub, for example, if some big aggressive guy asks you if you want a punch in the mouth, you say *"No!"*, not *"Nope!"*. Using the latter would probably get you beaten up, simply because it would sound as if you were making light of the situation.

Comment: Indeed; there are sources that say that "nope" is less emphatic. Updated answer.

Comment: *Nope* is more of an opposite to *yep* or *yup*, since they are both in the same register.

Comment: I'll reverse my downvote now you've removed the "less emphatic" stuff. Which of course was the main reason I posted an answer in the first place, so most of that might as well be removed now as well. But I'm going to keep my answer because you've missed a subtle point. You linked to J.R.'s answer on ELU, but notice his "*you might use it* to answer a yes-or-no question". Implying other ways you might. But John Lawler (the other answer) echoes it as "occurs *only* as a one-word answer to Y/N". Definitely no other possibilities there.

Comment: "nope". Is it a slang?

Answer (score 28):

The first and most important point to note it that it's *very* informal (more so than using contractions such as my ***it's*** there, for example).

The main reason for using it at all stems from that "extreme informality". It normally conveys a *relaxed attitude* on the part of the speaker. Depending on context, it can be more *or* less emphatic than "No".

You only use *nope* to mean ***[my answer is] "No"*** – it never replaces *no* in any other contexts. And you wouldn't normally use it where you want to be *very* emphatic (shouting "No!" at the top of your voice). Which example illustrates a defining characteristic – "Nope" isn't often followed by an exclamation mark!

Finally, I'd echo [John Lawler's](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59670/2637) words: *"nope" occurs **only as a one-word answer** to Y/N questions*. That's to say, a written form such as:

> "Nope I *don't* want to"

doesn't look right. We expect a full stop (or at the very least a comma) after "Nope" because in real-world speech there always would be a pause there. But that doesn't happen with:

> "No I *don't* want to!"

because it's perfectly possible to speak those words without pausing appreciably after "No" (without necessarily placing extra stress on *"don't"*, either; I just italicised it as one possible enunciation).

Comment: I think it is not so much emphatic as terminal or dismissive. It's not actually a distinct word: it's just *no* pronounced with a conclusive closing of the mouth which produces an effect *like* an unaspirated /p/. It's a gesture: no, and that's all I have to say.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well it seems to me that a "terminal/dismissive" negative response is effectively the same thing as an *emphatic* one. It's a moot point whether *no* and *nope* are "the same" word, given that OP is asking what differences might exist between them. And apart from the informality, I think it's significant you'd rarely if ever shout *"Nope!"* at the top of your voice as a one-word rejection.

Comment: I agree that you don't shout *Nope!* - shouting is a challenge. *Nope* always has so to speak a period at the end. Your interlocutor may take offense at the dismissal; you may even intend him to do so; but you are affecting a posture of disinclination to pursue the matter further. Or as you say, you're making light of the situation.

Comment: I disagree; "No, I don't want to!" requires a comma after "No" just as much as "Nope, I don't want to!" requires it after "Nope."  Omitting the comma would be informal (at best) in either case.

Comment: @Kyralessa: I'm not really interested in orthographic conventions - I'm talking about *language* here, which is essentially *spoken*.  Perhaps I should have given my example as *No I don't!*, since that would still illustrate my substantive point (that *Nope I don't* is non-idiomatic) without getting bogged down in how acceptable it is to omit that comma in the written form.

Comment: Yes, but "Nope. I don't." with an audible shift in tone is idiomatic. I agree it is spoken, and informal. You wouldn't say: Nope to the Queen of England. Just saying.....Usually, it does not stand on its own.  It's  usually in a context where an argument is going on though not always.

Answer (score 10):

"Nope" is informal.  You wouldn't usually want to use it, for example, answering questions for a job interview, but it would be an appropriate answer to a friend's question "Have you seen that movie yet?"

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion Nope is a dismissive and slightly rude version of no. Nope should never be used in a professional context e.g. it should never be used as an option for web site or search engine users to select as a response to a question, because it makes the company using it look un-professional and rude to their customers.  The use of the word nope by Google and others makes me cringe so much that I will never click on it in response to a question.

Comment: By being less professional they probably intended to come across as friendly, rather than rude.

Answer (score 4):

Nope is used informally, normally during chat where you want to give a quick, fluid answer to a question without halting it like 'No' would.

They both mean the same thing, and 'Nope' is very rarely written.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's another nuance in meaning beyond the informal vs formal. For instance:

> You don't think I'm pretty.

If someone responds "no" it is because he is disagreeing with the statement - he actually does think the speaker is pretty.

If someone responds "nope" it is because he agrees with the implication - he really does not think the speaker is pretty.

It's a subtle difference, but one to note.

Comment: The difference you proper isn't subtle, your two meanings are contradictory.  That is not any usage that i have ever encouñtered.

Answer (score 2):

*Nope* is an informal variant of one of the meanings *No* which is:

> 3 :  not so —used to express negation, dissent, denial, or refusal (**e.g.** no, I'm not going)
>   
> [Webster-Merriam](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no)

That is why, we can only use it for *Yes/No questions*.

Comment: Nope. Expressing denial doesn't need to follow a question. However, +1, because what you *can't* say is *no* to something that *isn't* a question. *No*. "No, what?" - "No to what you just said. I disagree. Nope. Un-uh. Ain't gonna happen."

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the person who says that nope is dismissive and slightly rude and I would add that a text nope feels rude to the recipient. It feels like a "final" no.

Answer (score 2):

I think the context has a lot to do with how the word Nope is perceived:

1. Somebody asks you for something.

   > - Will you do something for me?
   > - Nope. << Rude
2. Somebody asks for information.

   > - Is your name Sam?
   > - Nope. << Playful / informal

Maybe the word Nope implies a casual, relaxed attitude, which in some cases may come off as dismissive.

Answer (score 2):

'Nope' is a variant of 'no' (exclamation).

First known use: 1888  ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nope#h1))

Phonologically, pronunciation can explain where the P came from.

Suppose someone asked you a question and you said 'No'. You'd usually pause after saying 'No' (exclamation) with your lips already positioned to articulate a P, that's why most people articulate a P. That's called *excrescent P*.  (Sometimes producing a little puff of air is for emphasising 'no' while leaving it unreleased indicates lazy and sloppy speech.)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a subtle difference between emphatic and dismissive or terminal.  And I think that nope is often used in the latter two ways. Think of how the lips must  close together and this gives nope its terminal feeling in a physical way. Pursed lips.  Can't pry them open.  Not going to change.